# GPIO not working on Raspberry PI 4 4GB

Tags: gpio, ubuntu, wiringpi, firmware

I have a RPi 4 running Raspbian with the Ubuntu Mate desktop environment, whenever I try to use the Wiring Pi library through a C script, to doesn't work at all. On using the gpio readall command I was shown the error

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ gpio readall
Oops - unable to determine board type... model: 17
```

How do I resolve this issue, I have tried reinstalling WiringPi but the outcome was the same, do I need to reinstall my OS ?

Comment: GPIO works WiringPi doesn't - it is deprecated.

Comment: @Milliways: [born again?](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi)

Comment: @Seamus No DEAD  - just not buried. It is slowly decaying and has limited support for Pi4, none for Pi400, CM4

Comment: @Milliways: You must have information not available to me. All I know for sure is that 2.52 still works on RPi4, and there is a GitHub site that claims to be furthering the project.

Comment: @Seamus I am aware of that site. It is an incomplete patch with much of the same limitations. I started on my own (using more modern API) but decided it was too convoluted. People would be better using other tools. Many only use gpio readall and I have written an enhanced gpioread.

Comment: @Milliways: My needs are simple. I like WiringPi because it has the `gpio` utility. And I suppose once the 5.5 kernel is incorporated, there will be other changes to GPIO programming.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say which version of Wiring Pi you were using. If you're **not** using ver 2.52, that could be the cause of your problem. Follow the [upgrade instructions](http://wiringpi.com/wiringpi-updated-to-2-52-for-the-raspberry-pi-4b/), check to make sure you have ver 2.52, and try again.

My experience was similar to yours. After performing the upgrade on my RPi 4, everything seems to work fine - on RPi OS.

As you'll learn after reading the [upgrade instructions](http://wiringpi.com/wiringpi-updated-to-2-52-for-the-raspberry-pi-4b/), the author of Wiring Pi has discontinued support for the library. However, it seems a new team has [moved the code to GitHub](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi), and will hopefully keep the project moving forward.

Comment: thanks,I upgraded the OS and got the correct version of wiring Pi but it still didnt work so I just went with the good old method of uninstalling and reinstalling and It worked

Comment: @pyramiskyma: Yeah - I don't know what happened there, but something to do with diffs between updating w/ `dpkj` & `debs` vs `apt` maybe. In any case, if this solved your problem, please [read this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) & make a decision. If you don't like mine, then please make your own answer & select that. Otherwise, your question becomes a "zombie" & is recirculated for answers *ad nauseum*.

Answer (score 0):

I recently went through this problem with ubuntu 20.10 on a RPI4 and CM4 and even running GPIO -v simply SEGV's..

As long as you have the dependancies.. its simple enough to upgrade to WiringPI 2.6 which works..

```
#git clone git@github.com:WiringPi/WiringPi.git
#cd WiringPi
#./build
```

At which point

```
root@ys:~/git/WiringPi# gpio -v
gpio version: 2.60
Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Gordon Henderson
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type: gpio -warranty

Raspberry Pi Details:
  Type: CM4, Revision: 00, Memory: 1024MB, Maker: Sony
  * Device tree is enabled.
  *--> Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 Rev 1.0
  * This Raspberry Pi supports user-level GPIO access.
```